# Google Sheets function to convert a String to readable URL

Tags: url, google-sheets

I search for a google-sheets function to convert a string to a readable URL

string:
"dies ist ein String in Deutsch mit scharfen ß und lästigen blöden Umlauten"

url:
"dies-ist-ein-string-in-deutsch-mit-scharfen-ss-und-laestigen-bloeden-umlauten"

- Ä to ae
- Ü to ue
- Ö to oe
- ä to ae
- ü to ue
- ö to oe
- ß to ss
- "space" to -

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A2), 
 "ä", "ae"), 
 "ü", "ue"),
 "ö", "oe"),
 "ß", "ss"), 
 " ", "-")
```

[image: 0]

---

for array take this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A2:A), 
 "ä", "ae"), 
 "ü", "ue"),
 "ö", "oe"),
 "ß", "ss"), 
 " ", "-")))
```

Comment: You need to add `lower` to get rid of the "surviving" capital letter; such as the "U" in "Umlauten"

Comment: This post saved my life today 

Answer (score 1):

Create this custom function

```
function multipass(text, ChangeFrom, ChangeTo) {
  ChangeFrom = ChangeFrom.map (String);
  var re = new RegExp(ChangeFrom.join('|'), 'g');
  return text.replace(re, function (match) {return 
  ChangeTo[ChangeFrom.indexOf(match)];});
}
```

From WebApps [Multiple substitutions in a single text](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92839/196152); courtesy of Norman of Anstruther.

My final answer:
`=lower(multipass(B1,D2:D9,E2:E9))` is a combination of `multipass` (to do the multiple conversions) and `lower` (to reduce any remaining Capital letters to lowercase).

---

[image]

---

**REVISION- find and replace values in the function**

```
function fandr(text) {
  // add key:value pairs to the "find_replace" variable
  var find_replace = {
    'Ä': 'ae',
    'Ü': 'ue',
    'Ö': 'oe',
    'ä': 'ae',
    'ü': 'ue',
    'ö': 'oe',
    'ß': 'ss',
    ' ': '-'
  };

  // loop through the keys and replace with the value
  Object.keys(find_replace).map(function(find) {
    var replace = find_replace[find];
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: find key: "+find+", replace value: "+replace);//DEBUG
    // note the "g" - this is to replace all the matches for the given key/value pair
    text = text.replace(find, replace, "g");
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: modified text = "+text);//DEBUG
  });
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Final modified text = "+text.toLowerCase());//DEBUG
  return text.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: thx for your fast reply. Is there also a way to set the translation table in the function? and not in a table in sheets?

Comment: @n8lauscher Revised code that includes "translation table" as part of the function. The code possibly looks long and complicated, but I have left a bunch of `Logger` statements in to assist with understanding what happens at each stage. In fact, other than the "translation table", the code is only four (4) lines.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a formula to convert generic encoded url to readable url
e.g. `are%20you%20a%20planner%20or%20spontaneous%3F` --> `are-you-a-planner-or-spontaneous`

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2, "%20", "-"), "%3F", ""), "%2C", ""), "%9D", ""), "%28a", ""), "%21", ""), "%E2", ""), "%29", ""), "%80", ""), "%99", ""), "%2F", ""), "%9C", ""), "%27s", ""), "%5B", "")
```